# Regular Expression to find character succession less than x number of times and more than y number of times?

Tags: regex

I am trying to find spaces that occur more than once in a row and less than 23 times in a row. I only need it to find the . What is regular expression for this?

I want \s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s (<--22 times) to be found along with \s\s\s\s but never do I want to find just one space nor more than 22 spaces.

Comment: You should check out [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info). The syntax you're looking for is `\s{2,22}`.

Comment: General tip: in this case, the answer is pretty language-agnostic -- most regex engines that support `\s` will support `\s{2,22}` -- but in general, when asking a regex question, you should also indicate what language or tool you're using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply `\s{2,22}`, that way it will match 2 to 22 spaces in a row